# Can I display an html page with a html page without frames?

Tags: css, html, frames, liquid-layout

I am new to html, css, and javascript. I remember being able to do this with frames 10 years ago when I messed around with html. I want a table of contents on my left and my content on the right. I have five html pages that I want to use as content. Can I make this happen where I have one page that has the navigation and title the same on all pages, and the five content pages in the content area without frames? I am using this html/css as a basis: [liquid two column page](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/two-liquid/). I am going to modify it to make the left section skinnier.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, do you want to create a template page? This is best done server side, such as PHP and use an include file for your header/footer/nav

Comment: Do you need the static table to be "immune" to postbacks? That is, is it ok for the table to "disappear" for a second between pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I take is using Jquery to do this. Instead of making multiple HTML, I just create different divs and use the .show()/.hide() features.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in looking at server side includes (SSI).  This would allow you to design the navigation panel once then insert it into your other pages.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm

There are also ways to do this with PHP or ASP.NET masterpages.

Comment: It all depends on what other technologies you are using and what you comfortable with. For personal projects, I have used Apache web server and SSI for page elements, like navigation, that carry across an entire site. At work, we are a .NET shop, so we use the .NET master pages functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said frames do you mean framesets?, If so would you consider using iframes?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="300" height="300" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```