# Changing from frameset/frame to iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am refreshing an older generation server-based web application which makes extensive use of   framesets and frames. I understand why frames are bad and iframes a better, HTML5 compliant solution.

What I'm struggling to achieve is the iframe equivalent of something easy to do with frames: a left 'menu' frame of fixed width, and a right 'content' frame which fills the remainder of width available, both with height 100%.

With frameset it is simply: `<frameset cols="300,*">...</frameset>`

With iframes the "*" isn't allowed to specify the remainder, dimensions must be specified as either px or %. Percent sounds like it should be ideal but it is not: if I make the browser 4000 px wide I want all the additional space to go into the content, not the menu.

Have searched widely and can't figure it out. I'm sure there's a simple css-based, non-js, HTML5-compliant way to do this, but I'm ignorant as to how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Comment: If I were you I'd drop the `iframes` as well. Just make this through CSS only. If you are using a serverside coding language such as `PHP` you could just do an `include("my_menu.php")` on all the pages to achieve the same thing as the `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin and Jules for your comments. Note both menu and contents are dynamically generated serverside and I don't want to have to regenerate the menu each time. I'm sure I could rewrite each frameset occurrence using AJAX techniques to do this elegantly, but I'd rather not, I'd like to do a simple port. It seems that in the headlong rush away from frames/iframes, we're losing some very powerful ways to do simple things!

Comment: The bandwidth needed to send the HTML of a menu repeatedly is tiny, the loss of bookmarking that comes from using frames is horrible. Losing frames is not a great loss.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to debate the merits of frames - I get they're bad. Back to solving the main problem: my 'menu' isn't a simple list of hardcoded hyperlinks, it's a complex multi-form / multi-function sidebar that presents options based on an extensive server-side analysis, taking say 5-10 seconds to generate. The HTML is indeed small, but the cost is on in server prep time. I don't want to have to regenerate the menu each time - nor rewrite the entire app. Does anybody have an answer to the original iframe question?