# How to add external html into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a HTML file index.HTML. i wanna load external files( 1.HTML, 2.HTML, 3.HTML) into a div on button click
my HTML is something like this

```
<div class="buttons">
<button  type="button">button1</button>
<button  type="button">button2</button>
<button  type="button">button3</button>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">

</div>
```

on click of button1 1.HTML content to be loaded in above div.
on click of button2, 2.HTML.. and etc.

i am very new to java script so let me know how to write a script for this.
Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Answer (score 1):

use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).. and data attirbutes .. 
try this

**html**

```
<div class="buttons">
<button  type="button" data-url="1.html">button1</button>
<button  type="button" data-url="2.html">button2</button>
<button  type="button" data-url="3.html">button3</button>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').load($(this).data('url'));
});
```

**NOTE:** the selector `$('button')` selects all the button present in the document.. so  its better you give them a class and select it to be specific using class selector `.`

to be more specific

```
$('.buttons > button').click(function(){
     $('.mydiv').load($(this).data('url'));
});
```

**OR**

```
<div class="buttons">
<button  type="button" data-url="1.html" class="btnclass">button1</button>
<button  type="button" data-url="2.html" class="btnclass">button2</button>
<button  type="button" data-url="3.html" class="btnclass">button3</button>
</div>

$(".btnclass").click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').load($(this).data('url'));
});
```

Comment: `.buttons > button` is quite enough. (I don't like to create new classes where's no need to.)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#mydiv').load('test.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to append html after

```
$('#').append('html content')
```

Comment: Read the question clearly. It is not about adding html content. It is about loading external html file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
  var file = $(this).attr('number')+'.html';
  $('.mydiv').load(file);
  })
})
<div class="buttons">
<button  number= '1'  type="button">button1</button>
<button  number= '2'  type="button">button2</button>
<button  number= '3'  type="button" >button3</button>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">

</div>
```