# Why are the frames in my code not showing up?

Tags: html, frame

I'm trying to make a basic two frame menu/content system, but for the life of me I can't get the frames to show up. Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="poetry.css" />
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <table id="navbar" align="center"><tr>
                <td class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                <td class="link"><a href="poetry.html">Poetry</a></td>
                <td class="link"><a href="essays.html">Essays</a></td>
                <td class="link"><a href="stories.html">Stories</a></td>
                <td class="link"><a href="about.html">About</a></td>
                <td><p id="icon">Craig InTheDell</p></td>
            </tr></table>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <frameset cols="30%, 70%">
            <frame src="temp.html">
            <frame src="content.html">
            </frameset>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="image"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place frames inside a document, then you must use `<iframe>`s.

A `<frameset>` and `<frames>` may only appear in a frameset document, where they appear *instead* of the `<body>`.

---

Frames (of all kinds) are, however, problematic and I recommend [looking at alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames) as well as not using [tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/) (your navigation is better expressed as a list) and performing [basic, automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/) on your markup.

Comment: So do I just replace <frame> with <iframe>?

Comment: And remove the frameset. And apply CSS to render them they way you want. … that's if you continue to use frames. I recommend not doing that.