# if some parts of the html are repeated in several documents, is it more efficient to load it in the js?

Tags: javascript, html, web

For example, say you have an information box that will be repeated in every single page. if i have this in the HTML, then every time i change it, ill have to change it in every single HTML file.
But if i load it in the javascript (as in the whole thing), then I'll only need to change the javascript. For example,

```
$("body").append('<div id="infobox">*whatever i need*</div>')
```

is this a better way or does it create more complications?
or are there more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: You have pure `html` & `javascript`?

Comment: The better way would be to include at the server side. Whats your backend ?

Comment: Isn't it more _efficient_ (in the sense of centralized and less error prone) to keep "HTML in HTML" and  JavaScript empty from HTML code whenever possible? Just keep it in a separate fragment and **load** it from JavaScript.

Comment: @mohkhan umm what is a backend?

Comment: @Adriano how do i load a segment of HTML in js?

Comment: Few options: create a HTML page with that fragment (for compatibility with some IE versions make it a valid HTML file) then load it with [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (you may even use the [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function). As alternative you may use iframe (if applicable you won't even need JavaScript).

Comment: I mean is your website static or does it have dynamic content as well ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Comment: @FSou1 yes im just using html css and js

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. You're on a slippery path there…
It might be more efficient for the person maintaining the page but you should really be doing this on the server-side as mohkhan suggested e.g. through a CMS or pre-processing if you're site is completely static. I assume that on your site, there isn't just an info box that's repeated — what about the navigational elements, the banner etc.? 
There's nothing wrong with loading elements through JavaScript (e.g. to show counters, data, etc.) but you shouldn't be doing it for core content. Remember too that you shouldn't assume  that everyone will have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: ah i see. i guess that's very true.