# How do you load a partial html in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement an index.html page with a partial page that contains links and logo, and change body content depending on the link click.

Is there a light js library that allows you to do that in html5?

Comment: you could do that with php, having a iclude file for the menu/static parts. Or use javascript/jQuery/Mootools or other to load it via ajax. Do you know how this could work? or its new to you?

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourContent').innerHTML = yourCode`? I would use PHP for this though

Comment: what you mean by partial?

Comment: Just use ajax.(not necessarily jQuery) This has been around a lot longer than jQuery o rHTML5

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Comment: loading a whole page into another page is totally wrong if you don't use iframe which is a bad thing. your probably searching for something to load in a static page without changing location and in this case you need ajax, which can load various files to the a simple static html pages. Probably the best&only approach is to use ajax in conjuction with json files. json contains data (like you mentioned urls,logos) that can be easely imported into javascript as values. In this case proposing jquery is not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jQuery

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you. This should work. I was trying to organize static html pages, and enforce DRY.