# call parital html page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want to call a partial html page using jquery. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385068/how-do-you-load-a-partial-html-in-html5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> $('#result').load('Ajax/test.html'); </script>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>

    </body>


</html>
```

and in the path `Ajax/test.html` i have this test.html:

```
<h1>Hey World</h1>
```

The problem is it does not load the `Hey World` into the main page. Also, **there is no error in console**.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with `$('#result')`, `jQuery` is unable to find the element as `DOM` is not ready hence `jQueryObject.load` method is never invoked.

Wrap your script in [**`$(document).ready`**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) **or** Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))

There are also [**`DOMContentLoad`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [**`window.onload`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) events which makes sure that `DOM` is loaded but IMO, placing `<script>` just before `</body>` is easier option.

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  $('#result').load('test.html');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `<script>` tag to include a `document.ready`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#result').load('Ajax/test.html');
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append to an element that yet does not exists.

Try adding your code in a `$(document).ready()`, and just before the `</body>` closing tag.

Like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').load('Ajax/test.html');
});
</script>

</body>
```