# How can I use html file into another one

Tags: html, frame

I am creating a web site include navigation bar using only front end code...html ,css and script. but I want to add nav bar in each page by an already created html file.

I am using HTML5 that deprecated frameset tag. So which technique could I use without other backend code to add that html file to another one? Thanks.

```
<frameset rows="200,*" frameborder="no" border="0" id="container" scrolling="yes">
    <frame src="nav.html" name="leftframe" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="nav" />
    <frame src="slider.html" name="rightframe" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="slider" />
    <frame src="text.html" name="bottomframe" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="text" />
    <frame src="copy.html" name="bottomframe" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="text" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to "include" html files.  Best bet is to use php - is this an option?

Comment: You can include it using jQuery Load() if you are using jQuery or you can use some php.For html , the only way to this is iframe

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch `<frame>` for the [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element and get the same results with some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
        $(function(){
         $("#navbar").load("navbar.html"); 
        });
      </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
   <div id="navbar"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Don't do that unless you also 
follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)