# Adding HTML menus to Includes(PHP)

Tags: php, html, include

I am making a website using HTML. I am not familiar with PHP. I need the navigation and header part to be in a single place. i.e., Once I change the menus in one place it should reflect in all other pages. Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Comment: kindly google `PHP Beginner Tutorial` yourself. Hint: `require` is the php command you are seraching for to include a file.

Comment: It's a legit question for someone who's only wish is to divide his HTML structure to files, you dont really need to know PHP to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use include or require to add your Menu-Html file in every page you wish.
you could add something like this:

```
<?php 
    include('menu.html');
?>
```

wherever your menu should appear in your HTML, having a menu.html file of course.
and you'll need an apache server or any other that can 'read' your php files.

[include php documentations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

[require php documentations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: Thanks. Which one will work on old browsers?. Includes or require?

Comment: php has no dependencies on browsers, so either one will do. you should read what's php is all about to better understand what you are about to do.

Comment: Thanks again. I got your point. A final doubt, as you said, if I save my menu as menu.html and include it on index.php, will it work? or do I need to save menu.html as menu.php?

Comment: you could include either a php or an html file. just make sure you are running apache or something similar that could handle php files.