# Showing complete frameset from child frame

Tags: html, frames

I have a simple frameset definition like this:

```
<frameset cols="280,*">
    <frame name="toc" src="toc.html">
    <frame name="main" src="main.html">
</frameset>
```

The left frame contains the table of contents of my document, the right frame the actual pages. Now people often link directly to the individual pages of my document which are shown in the "main" frame. The problem with direct links to the pages to be shown in the "main" frame is that the browser will obviously open them without any frameset because the individual pages don't contain any frame definitions. However, this is very confusing for the reader because she/he needs the table of contents frame in order to navigate through the document.

So I'd like to solve this problem via one of the following approaches:

1) If the user links directly to a page to be displayed in the "main" frame, the browser should automatically set up the complete frameset. Is this possible somehow? If not, please see approach number 2.

2) I could add a "Show TOC" button to the end of every page. This button could then point to another HTML page which sets up the frameset, putting the current page in the "main" frame. The problem is that I would need dozens of dummy HTML pages then because I'd need one for every single page because the "src" HTML for the "main" frame is different from page to page. Or is there an easier solution to that?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Or is there an easier solution to that?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames

Comment: Yes, I know that frames are so 90s but I currently don't have the time to recreate the whole shebang using modern technologies. So... is one of my ideas possible with traditional frames?