# Why are the framesets not loading in the page?

Tags: html, css, frameset

Here is the code that I used for a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd”>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>This page illustrates frame sets</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <frameset rows="30%,*,20%">
                <frame name="one" src="styledform.html" />
                <frame name="two" src="index.html" />
                <frame name="three" src="form.html" />
            </frameset>
        </body>
</html>
```

The html files `styledform.html`, `index.html` and `form.html` are all present in the same folder as the file whose source code I have displayed above.

When I try to open the above link in Google Chrome browser, I see a blank page.
What is the error?

Comment: Your double quotes in your DOCTYPE line seem to invalid

Comment: You probably found a really old tutorial somewhere, or you are just oldschool ;) Anyway, I would really advise you to _not_ use framesets. There are numerous other ways to separate blocks of content, amongst others including parts with a scripting language, or loading content using AJAX. Framesets are obsolete in the current html specifications, and will never ever return.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of errors in your document that [a validator](http://validator.w3.org) would identify for you.

The one that is causing the problem you are asking about is that a frameset document must have a `<frameset>` element **instead of** a `<body>` element and not **inside** one.

When the browser encounters the `<body>` start tag, it generates a regular HTML document and then discards the `<frameset>` as invalid.

That said, don't use frames. There are [better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames).

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `doctype`. There are correct definitions

- HTML 4.01 Frameset

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
  ```
- XHTML 1.0 Frameset

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
  ```