# Same Html across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to have a chunk of html containing a heading which i want to reuse across multiple html pages.

I have tried the EXACT code but it doesn't seem to work. it is displaying the script in HTML rather than actioning it.

index.html:

```
    <html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>

   <script>$("#content").load("commonContent.html");</script>

    </html>
```

commonContent.html:

```
<div id="content"><h2>If this shows my test worked!</h2></div>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Please note i am a newbie to javascript!

Comment: javascript code must be between `<script>` tags in your html.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. To include [the jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) since your script depends on it
2. To put your script inside a `<script>` element
3. To put an element in the document in which you will load the content (you are trying to use one with `id="content"` but no such element exists).

I'd recommend using a [server side or build time template system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9466333/19068) instead though. They are more reliable and better food for search engines.

Comment: 3. Define an element with ID "content". 0. Write valid HTML

Comment: @Jonathan — Good spot.

Comment: @Jonathan Hi, Isn't that what i have done in my commonContent.html?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your comment. I have now edited my doc to add <script> & updated the question with my updated code. 

How do i include the jQuery library?

Comment: @JessMurray Yes, but that won't help: http://api.jquery.com/load/. Please just start by reading the basics of writing valid HTML.

Comment: @Jonathan — You can't load `commonContent.html` into a div that is on `commonContent.html` and not in the current page. The jQuery website includes instructions on how to set up jQuery for your site.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of thing I usually use php like this:

```
<?php include("youhtmlfile.html"); ?>
```

It is an advantage because this way you don't have to worry about browser support.

Comment: Hi, I tired this and it didn't to work. With research i also tried:<?php include 'try.html';?>

Comment: what's the content of your html file? when you tested out my code was your html file the same as in the example in your question? Do you have php installed?

Comment: You've forgotten some key aspects that need to be addressed for this to work. I have edited your answer to properly display this