# Web navigation - How to link HTML documents

Tags: html

how can I connect my navigation bar to my html files?

```
<header class="mainheader">     
        <!--Postavi snimkata za logoto!!!-->
        <img src="star_shine2.png">     

        <nav><ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#index.html">История на зодиака</a></li>
            <li><a href="index1.html">Видове зодии</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Зодиакална прогноза</a></li>
            </ul></nav> 
</header>   
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="content">
                <article class="topcontent">
                    <header>
```

Comment: You need to more accurately describe what you want and what the problem is. (The # in "#index.html" is probably not what you want)

Comment: *possible* duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but I answer fo what I understood.

```
 <a href="www.sitename.com/HTMLfilename.html">Home</a>
```

(or)

```
  <a href="HTMLfilename.html">Home</a> ( if you have the file in root)
```

take out that #

Answer (score 0):

simply write the name of the page i.e index1.html with # sign
eg.

```
<li><a href="#index1.html"></a></li>
```