# Affect embed element from parent

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an group of html pages. They load the header, logo, menu, and footer from separate html pages using embed. What I want to do is change the color of the current page catagory in the menu. Before I moved to using embed, I just did:

```
<li><a href="./CurrentPage.html" class="current">CurrentPage</a></li>

menu li a.current {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I'm just starting to get into web design, hence the noob question.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I moved away from using iframe to embed. I really need this to be 100% client side. I'm using Dropbox to host my pages for now, hence the lack of SSI. Perhaps JavaScript is my best option?...

Thanks

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: _“They load the header, logo, menu, and footer from separate html pages using iframe”_ – that is a really bad setup. You should try to not use iframes for this, but instead make each page a “full” HTML document that contains all those parts already. If your main concern is the “work” this requires, then look into _includes_ (either server-side, or in your editor).

Comment: I'd suggest using [something other than frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames) for your problem.

Comment: I moved from using iframe to embed (thank you html5). My problem still stands.