# How do I create a link in HTML and CSS which will populate a div or other element with an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's been a long time since I last had to do any html, but one of the features that will apparently still work, but is not good practice, was to divide a page into frames and the you could use some sort of nav bar with all the page links to populate a targeted frame. eg.

```html
<a href="somecontent.html" target="middleframe">clicky</a>
```

I tried using the `<iframe>` tag, and although it's *almost* exactly what I want, I found it to be very frustrating to get it to autosize to the correct height depending on the content being loaded into it.

Obviously, I could just make an almost identical page but change the content on the new one and link from one to the other, but I have a rather nice css slideshow as my background for the site and I don't want it to reload every time a link is clicked!

Now, I'm loving stylesheets and divs, so is there any way to do the above without resorting to HTML 4? I'll take a javascript answer if there really is *no way* to do this in CSS and HTML 5.

Thanks in advance, you lovely people!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames

Comment: You need JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just want to update the actual content, that differs? You could do it with iFrames, but this is not recommended at all.

**The "new" way to use is called "AJAX"**

It is a technique to download data from the server, without reloading the current page. This is done via JavaScript (and serverside PHP). That way you can update the page content only.
There are many tutorials on the web, also many common questions are answered on stackoverflow alreay. Feel free to check them out :)

Comment: idk why someone downvoted, but AJAX is the correct answer

Comment: Thank you for this!