# URLs not working as HTML frame src

Tags: html, frames

I have the following HTML code which is not giving any output on neither Mozilla nor IE. The status bar shows connected to www.Facebook.com & www.yahoo.com but then the pages are not displayed. I've tested in Mozilla & IE.

```
<HTML>   
  <head>
      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <frameset cols="50%,50%">
      <frame src="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=gmail" />
      <frame src="http://www.facebook.com/login.php" />
  </frameset>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I hope this is a typo: `<frame src=<frame src=`.

Comment: Just tested that iframe in Firefox, the `search.yahoo.com` website works well, but `facebook.com` refuses to load in iframe - you get only empty page in the right side frame.

Answer (score 1):

`frameset` tag always requires a `DOCTYPE` tag.

**Note:** If you want to validate a page containing frames, be sure the  is set to either "HTML Frameset DTD" or "XHTML Frameset DTD".

P.S.: Not sure if this requirement is there or not from HTML5.

Comment: With regards to frames and HTML5: [Any way of using frames in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846019/any-way-of-using-frames-in-html5). Frames are obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks for the read. :) Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<frame src=<frame src="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=gmail" />
```

take away the first `'<frame src='`

Comment: okay sorry for that inconvenient line. But still its not working.