# Dynamically causing a change in one PHP file when an action is encountered in another PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

I have two PHP files being shown to the user using frames. 
(Below is a small portion of the code from the two files)

**First PHP file** - *q11.php*

```
echo "<form action = 'q21.php' method = 'post' id = 'sub1'>";
    echo "<br><input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'a'>";
    echo "<br><input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'b'>";
    echo "<br><input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'c'>";
    echo "<br><input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'd'>";
echo "</form>";
```

**Second PHP file** - *status.php*

```
echo "<h4 id = 'q1'>Question 1";
```

Now, when the user clicks on any of the submit buttons belonging to the first PHP file (q11.php), I want to change the colour of the h4 element in the second PHP file (status.php).

Thank you for the guidance and help in advance.

Comment: Why you using 4 submit button in a single form?

Comment: How are the 2 pages related ?

Comment: you can do it using jquery

Comment: @hoijui It can't be a unrelated PHP question, there must be a way do it in PHP, check the answer below.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. [Frames are not supported in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) However You can use single file to handle Your logic [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NpWnHJHc).

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Yeah it's true, frameset is deprecated in html5, but it still works - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4846132/3944217. By the way anjha doesn't mention HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

**First Page**

```
<form action = 'status.php' method = 'post' id = 'sub1'>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'a'><br>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'b'><br>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'c'><br>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'ans' value = 'd'>
</form>
```

**Second Page: status.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['ans'])
{
    $ans=$_POST['ans'];
    if($ans=='a')
    {
        $color='blue';
    }
    if($ans=='b')
    {
        $color='red';
    }
    if($ans=='c')
    {
        $color='green';
    }
    if($ans=='d')
    {
        $color='yellow';
    }
}
?>
<h4 id = 'q1' style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>">Question 1</h4>
```

Try this...