# HTML5 <Frameset>

Tags: php, html, frameset

Hey everyone I'm trying to learn PHP and I am using this tutorial right now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eDklLtzuB4

But at the 10:50 mark in the video the following code is used:

```
<FRAMESET cols="200,*">
    <FRAME src="sidebar.php">
    <FRAMESET rows="*,200">
        <FRAME src="messages.php">
        <FRAME src="newmessages.php">
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

And to my understanding, this is outdated and doesn't work with HTML5. 
Can anyone offer an alternative solution ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846019/any-way-of-using-frames-in-html5 "Any way of using frames in HTML5?"