# Does HTML5 support frameset element?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have multiple pages in web application, I want to make multiple views of these pages on a single page. then someone prefer for `<FRAMESET>` element because the `<FRAMESET>` element holds one or more `<frame>` elements. Each `<frame>` element can hold a separate document.

Does HTML5 support `<frameset>` element or not?

Comment: have you considered using divs

Comment: please visit page : [html5 support frame set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846019/any-way-of-using-frames-in-html5)

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846019/any-way-of-using-frames-in-html5