# How to make framesets work in HTML5

Tags: html

I have the following code. As i understand frames / framesets will not work in HTML5. So, how can i make it work ? if i wanted the same result to work in HTML5, what should i do ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    Header stuff herer
      screen" title="Screen" charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <frameset cols="100%" frameborder="0">
        <frameset rows="<?php echo SITE_CONFIG_TOP;?>, *">
            <frame src="framedTop.php?url=<?php echo $shortUrlObj->shortUrlUID; ?>" class="framedTopFrame" noresize scrolling="no"/>
            <frame src="<?php echo $shortUrlObj->fullUrl;?>" noresize>/
        </frameset>
        <noframes>
            <?php echo t("browser_no_frame");?>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way of using frames in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846019/any-way-of-using-frames-in-html5)

Comment: They *do* work, see [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/4846132/962603).